# Dart: Calling a function that takes a Nullable argument is giving me an unexpected error (1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.)

Tags: dart, nullable

The default value is null so calling the function with no arguments should be fine!

```
 void main() {
 shout();
}

void shout(String? name) {
  if (name != null) {
    print('Hello, $name!');
  } else {
    print('Hello, stranger!');
  }
}
```

Comment: `name` is defined as a [required positional parameter](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#parameters). For an [optional positional parameter](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#optional-positional-parameters) you need to wrap the parameter in `[]`.  Or make it an optional [named parameter](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#named-parameters) by wrapping it in `{}`.

Comment: Nullable positional parameters are not implicitly optional.  They're no different from non-nullable positional parameters except that `null` is a valid argument.  For better or worse, there is [a proposal to make nullable parameters implicitly optional](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/2232), however.

Answer (score 1):

warp it with optional bracket `{String? name}`.

```
void main() {
shout();
}

void shout({String? name}) {
  if (name != null) {
    print('Hello, $name!');
  } else {
    print('Hello, stranger!');
  }
}
```

Comment: why do i need brackets? I should not need them!

Comment: if you not use brackets the func expect a parameter, even its null its still an object. in bracket you can specify it. same with this `void foo(dynamic)` , foo() takes a parameter, null or not you specify it. so you need bracket  `{}` or `(arr,[optional])`to declare a optional parameter